# Uninstalled Program While Running and Did Not Really Uninstall

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

On the latest version of Windows 10, I uninstalled Audacity because I was having trouble with it and wanted to re-install it. However, I didn't realize that Audacity was open while I uninstalled it from Settings -> Storage -> Apps & features. Now, when I click on Audacity in the taskbar it still opens and runs like it did before. Is there a way to uninstall a program that no longer shows up in Settings or Control Panel? I looked in Control Panel and it was not in the list of applications/programs.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Restart, install Audacity again, restart, now uninstall it while it is not running.

Comment: Thank you John, that worked.

Comment: I posted an answer for you and I trust you will mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Audacity was open while I uninstalled it from Settings -> Storage ->
> Apps & features. Now, when I click on Audacity in the taskbar it still
> opens and runs like it did before. Is there a way to uninstall a
> program that no longer shows up in Settings or Control Panel?

The easiest way to solve this kind of problem is to reinstall the program before trying to uninstall. This resets the uninstall capability.

Restart the computer.

Install Audacity again, and restart.

Now uninstall it while it is not running.

Now that it is working, you can install Audacity or leave uninstalled as you wish.

Comment: Thank you for considering to make sure it worked before even posting as an answer! That shows the signs of a great helper!